# Chrome extension : Stuck at injecting script won't execute js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a chrome extension. Which would do some search on the page and post the results to the extensions.

I am having a hard time running this. Whenever I try to run the extension it is just stuck on Injecting Script.

my **re.js**

```
function printDetails(document_r) {
var test = document_r.body; 
var text = test.innerText;
var delim="^^ validatedCache :";
var endlim="</site>";
var idx = text.indexOf(delim);
var endInd=text.indexOf(endlim);
var tag = "accountName";
var regex = "<" + tag + ">(.*?)<\/" + tag + ">";
var regexg = new RegExp(regex,"g");
var matches = [];
while (match = regexg.exec(text.substring(idx+delim.length,endInd))) matches.push("Account Name::::::"+match[1]);
return matches;
    }

chrome.extension.sendMessage({
    action: "getSource",
    source: "\n\n\n DETAILS>>>>>\n\n"+printDetails(document)
});
```

**selection.js**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
  if (request.action == "getSource") {
    message.innerText =  request.source;
  }
});

function onWindowLoad() {

  var message = document.querySelector('#message');

  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    file: "re.js"
  }, function() {
    // If you try and inject into an extensions page or the webstore/NTP you'll get an error
    if (chrome.extension.lastError) {
      message.innerText = 'There was an error injecting script : \n' + chrome.extension.lastError.message;
    }
  });

}

window.onload = onWindowLoad;
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style=''>
<head>
<script src='selection.js'></script>
</head>
<body style="background-image:url(12.png);width:400px; border: 2px solid black;background-color:white;">
<div id='message'>Injecting Script....</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know there is some problem with these 2 lines only.

```
var test = document_r.body; 
var text = test.innerText;
```

What I wan't is to extract the webpage  ( contents ) into a string which I am hopefully doing by the above two lines of code.

Then do some string manipulation on the code.If I run directly this code in a console with a dummy string . I can execute it so figure something is wrong with these two lines.

My extension is stuck on " Injecting Script..."

Some help would be appreciated.

PS:yes I was able to run it earlier with the same code but somehow it doesn't run now.

Comment: You should use `innerHTML` instead of `innerText`

Comment: didn't solve my purpose Still stuck at injecting script.

Comment: @rsanchez : I tried textContent too :(

Comment: Did you include the `activeTab` permission in your manifest?

Comment: sorry no clue about this . Can you please elaborate @rsanchez

Comment: @rsanchez : tried activeTab still stuck .

Comment: The `message` variable is not accessible by `onMessage` because it is declared locally in `onWindowLoad`. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html#inspect-popup to learn how to debug such problems yourself in the future.